# Toolbar and ActionBar with NavigationUI

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-toolbar, android-jetpack-navigation

I have a `Toolbar` in my XML layout of the main activity. When I create a `Toolbar` with the `NavigationUI` as described at https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-ui , then is it also too much when I create an `ActionBar` with the `NavigationUI`? So, in my main activity I have the following:

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
     // AppBar configuration
     appBarConfiguration =AppBarConfiguration.Builder(setOf(R.id.homeFragment)).build()
     // NavController object
     val navController: NavController = findNavController(R.id.myNavHostFragment)
     // create Toolbar using NavigationUI method
     setupToolbar(navController, appBarConfiguration)

     // create ActionBar using NavigationUI method
     setupActionBar(navController, appBarConfiguration)
}

private fun setupToolbar(navController: NavController, appBarConfiguration: AppBarConfiguration) {
     binding.toolbar.setupWithNavController(navController, appBarConfiguration)
}

private fun setupActionBar(navController: NavController, appBarConfiguration: AppBarConfiguration) {
     setupActionBarWithNavController(navController, appBarConfiguration)
}
```

I am a little bit confused. Do I need both of them ? Do I need only the `setupToolbar()` ? What is the difference between them ?

Hope someone can help.

Answer (score 2):

It depends on what you use. If you use a `<toolbar>` in XML then you have to use only `setupToolbar`. But if you use default `ActionBar`, which is provided by `Theme.AppCompat.Light` in `style.xml` then you have to use `setupActionBar()`.

It seems that you use default `ActionBar`. Try to use only `setupToolabr()` method.